# How to accept all filetypes except for .exe via the <input type="file"> control

Tags: html, dom, input, mime-types

```
<input id="upload" accept=".pdf, .xml, .docx" multiple="" hidden="" type="file">
```

Is it possible to make it so that any file type is selectable except for .exe using the 'accept' attribute?

Comment: You can listen the input's onChange event and then check the extensions of files. But even the extension of file is different from 'exe' it can be still an executable file. So that mime types should be more stable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use

> The string audio/* meaning "any audio file".
>
> The string video/* meaning "any video file".
>
> The string image/* meaning "any image file".

From [MDN uniqe file type specifiers wild card](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#Unique_file_type_specifiers)

**Note**: make sure you also limit the extensions on your backend as someone could still use another tool to post an `.exe` to your endpoint